# How to make my script menu execute my subscripts in Unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Sorry in advance since i am new to Unix coding. I have a Bash shell script that generates 2 other subscripts. The main script implements a menu that gives a choice to the user in which script to generate. 
I have two problems. The first one is how to make the script that the user selects to execute when he selects it, and the second how to implement input validation in my menu so when the user inputs something different that 1 and 2 to get an error message. This is my code so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Welcome to scriptGen."
echo "Please select a script to execute by choosing 1 or 2:"

scripts="bDir mMail"

select option in $scripts
do
        echo "You have selected script $option to execute."
done
cat > bDir.sh <<EOF1
#!/bin/bash
#code
EOF1
chmod +x bDir.sh

cat >mMail.sh <<EOF2
#!/bin/bash
#code
EOF2
chmod +x mMail.sh
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you'll probably want a `case` statement for your user to select their input.

Also, I'm not sure what you're doing with the dynamic writing of scripts, but you'll probably be better off with functions in your code.

Something like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

main () {
    echo "Welcome to scriptGen."
    echo
    echo "1: bDir"
    echo "2: mMail"
    echo -n "Please select a script to execute by choosing 1 or 2: "

    read user_input

    case $user_input in
        1)
            bdir
            ;;
        2)
            mmail
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Unrecognised option '$user_input'. Exiting..."
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac
}

bdir () {
    echo "Running bDir"
}

mmail () {
    echo "Running mmail"
}

main "$@"
```

---

**Explanation:**

```
main () {
...
}
```

Creating a function called `main`. It's a clear enough name to let the user know what function is going to get called first.

---

```
echo -n "Please select a script to execute by choosing 1 or 2: "
```

The `-n` removes the new-line at the end. This gives a nicer user experience when they're prompted.

---

```
read user_input
```

Read the user's input and store it in the variable `user_input`. The capture will finish when the user presses enter. However, this can be combined with other flags like `-n 1` to capture just 1 character and continue without requiring the user to press enter.

---

```
case $user_input in
    1)
        bdir
        ;;
    2)
        mmail
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Unrecognised option '$user_input'. Exiting..."
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

A case statement. Given the value of user_input, if it's 1, run the `bdir` function. If it's 2 run the `mmail` function. Otherwise, echo the warning and exit.

---

```
main "$@"
```

Run our main function. We use `$@` to ensure all of the variables passed into the script are also passed into the main function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and your thorough explanation! I just have one more question! If i wanted the main script to do something else, for example check whether a file exists, i have to do that outside of the main function right?

Comment: You can do it within the main function or without. The word `main` is arbitrary, and it's just a nicer way to group up your code and is mainly down to preference.

Comment: i have another question if it's not much trouble. I want to create a script that asks the user for his username and check if its valid by verifying the user home directory exists. If the username exists it should send an email to the user from a predifined .txt file. If the user does not exist it should persist until a valid username is given. Also if the word "exit" is submited as username the script should exit. This is what i have done so far:

Comment: `#!/bin/bash
echo "Input your username"
dir="/home"
read username

if [[ -d $dir/$username ]]
then 
cat Message.txt | mailx -s "Subject" $username
else
echo "The user does not exist. Please type a valid username."
fi`

Comment: I think the part with the message is fine(not sure though) but i have problems with the exit and the input validation! Thanks again for your time and help!